# How to sign a signature for AWS4 (python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a AWS project and need to get a signature in order to authenticate myself before i can http post an audio file to my s3 bucket

I have the following python code following the AWS documentation(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) and their examples :

```
import hmac
import hashlib

def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(("AWS4" + key).encode("utf-8"), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, "aws4_request")
    kFinal = kSigning.encode("hex")
    return kFinal


def finalsignature (key,msg):
    kFinalSign = sign (key, msg)
    kFinalSignature = kFinalSign.encode("hex")
    return kFinalSignature
    return kFinalSign

val = getSignatureKey("wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY","20151229","us-east-1","s3")

KKfinalsignature = finalsignature(val,"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")

print (val) #prints out the signing key
print ('\n')
print (KKfinalsignature)#prints out the final signature
```

---

The signing key should be correct based on my previous attempts with other examples but my code can't seem to sign the final signature properly as instead of getting:

correct signature:

```
8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e
```

my code output:

```
074f00bbb8e273a0430131de18ed898fd3ad31663d7aed7835d7b658e689d64d
```

Can someone check out what is wrong with my code ?

Thanks!!!

Comment: are these signatures real? if yes please replace them with dummy values for security

Comment: Why not use boto3 instead of building this signing code yourself?

Comment: I'd use boto3 to pre-sign URLs, but if for some reason you do not want to or cannot then there are numerous v4 signing resources available in Python (https://www.google.com/search?q=python+aws4).

Answer (score 0):

The signing key should not be hex encoded before creating the signature.  It should be used in its binary form.

Instead of:

```py
    kSigning = sign(kService, "aws4_request")
    kFinal = kSigning.encode("hex")
    return kFinal
```

do:

```py
    kSigning = sign(kService, "aws4_request")
    return kSigning
```

---

Full script:

```
import hmac
import hashlib

def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(("AWS4" + key).encode("utf-8"), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, "aws4_request")
    return kSigning


def finalsignature (key,msg):
    kFinalSign = sign (key, msg)
    kFinalSignature = kFinalSign.encode("hex")
    return kFinalSignature
    return kFinalSign # [DO NOT HEX ENCODE HERE]

val = getSignatureKey("wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY","20151229","us-east-1","s3")

KKfinalsignature = finalsignature(val,"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")

print (val.encode("hex")) #prints out the signing key. [HEX ENCODE HERE]
print ('\n')
print (KKfinalsignature)#prints out the final signature
```